# Create table in SQL Server from hbm mapping file and class nHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I am a beginner in nHibernate . I created mapping files and classes in Visual Studio. Now I want the tables to be created in SQL Server by writing code , not by manually adding tables in SSMS. Is there any way to do so? I have more than 50 classes. I have both .hbm.xml and .cs class files.

Comment: Have a look at fluent NHibernate. With it it is possible to create your tables. Another plus: You can remove the xml mappings and map your entities in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

If you want to do this explicitly, then you want to call SchemaExport.

to create tables

```
new SchemaExport(Configure).Create(false, true);
```

to drop tables

```
new SchemaExport(Configure).Drop(false, true);
```

Per moh.mehrabi's answer you can use the property hbm2ddl.auto.  I'd be wary of nHibernate running schema changes every time it starts up.  This property just fronts the SchemaExport class.

This explains that configuration element [link](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/11/22/nhibernate-hbm2ddl.html)

And [here's](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-schema-auto-action) how to set it if using the nHibernate loquacious mapping

Answer (score 0):

its better to show me your Web.config file.in your file you must add this property:

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: sir can you please look at it now. I have edited to show nhibernate configuration file